# android uiautomator cause "unfortunately, settings has stopped" error

Tags: android, android-uiautomator

```
    getUiDevice().pressHome();      
    new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("Apps")).click(); 
    new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Apps")).click();        
    new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).setAsHorizontalList().scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text("Settings"));
    new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Settings")).click();
    new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollTextIntoView("Accessibility");        
    new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Accessibility")).click();
```

The finall line of code cuase the following error on my Nexus 4, i tried to google it, but can't find any related information, so can anybody help explain why the error happend?

```
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.android.settings/com.android.settings.SubSettings}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2819)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at com.android.settings.AccessibilitySettings.loadInstalledServices(AccessibilitySettings.java:586)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at com.android.settings.AccessibilitySettings.onResume(AccessibilitySettings.java:196)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1738)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:919)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1039)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1850)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5221)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2780)
10-23 13:43:16.466: E/AndroidRuntime(7995):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: Have you managed to fix this issue? I am facing the exact issue in my app now.

Comment: I've been getting this error in Google Play Console's Pre-Launch report when my app links to the accessibility settings.

Answer (score 1):

Should be an easy fix. When you are navigating through the app, (i.e. loading an app or a new page, or anything that needs to load) instead of using

```
 new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("Apps")).click(); 
 new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Apps")).click();
```

Try using

```
 new UiObject(new UiSelector().description("Apps")).clickAndWaitForWindow(); 
 new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Apps")).clickAndWaitForWindow();
```

Comment: This issue at had isn't waiting or not waiting.  The issue is that AccessibilitySettings is throwing a Null Pointer Exception while loading services.
So the question is what doesn't get set when launch through testing that does get set when manually going there.

Comment: Any solution for this issue ?